# Docker image is completely borked and won't start

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running Docker for Windows and trying to build an image.  It was working great, but then I added this to the end of my Dockerfile:

```
# Install Python
RUN choco install -y python3 --params "/InstallDir:C:\Python"
ENV PYTHONPATH=C:\Python\python.exe
```

When I did that, the image built but when I tried to run it, I got:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from daemon: container
>   9e758f7ef343436f64e7e29b795154b1e771a6682b625097d680e3b510a9047c
>   encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call:
>   The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106).

So, I removed the two lines and rebuilt.  Yet, when I tried to run it (which was now reverted to the version that previously worked!) I still got the error.  How can I clear out whatever was messed up?  So far, I've tried the following:

- Restarted Docker
- Restarted Windows
- Ran `docker rmi -f` on the image, and anything that looked like some sort of intermediary build image with no tag.
- Ran `docker system prune`
- Rebuilt the image with a `--no-cache`
- Tried giving both the build and run more memory with `--memory=8G`
- Cursed various deities

Also, note the image (the complete one, including the lines which install Python) builds *and runs* on my other machine which is running Windows Server 2016.  So, the image is fine.  There's something screwed up with this computer that I can't seem to undo.  I suppose re-installing Docker is my next step unless anyone has a better idea.

**Docker Verison:**

```
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:21:34 2018
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:36:40 2018
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

**Entire Dockerfile:**

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1 as vsbuild

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing below.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Static Analysis Tools
RUN C:\TEMP\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2018.1.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016

COPY --from=vsbuild ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/Team Tools", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/Team Tools"]
COPY --from=vsbuild ["C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/CodeAnalysis", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/BuildTools/MSBuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/CodeAnalysis"]

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Install Chocolatey
ADD https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 C:\TEMP\chocolatey.ps1
RUN C:\TEMP\chocolatey.ps1

# Install Node.js
RUN choco install -y nodejs

# Install Gulp
RUN choco install -y gulp-cli

# Install SQL Command Line Utilities
RUN choco install -y sqlserver-cmdlineutils

# Install Azure Powershell
RUN choco install -y azurepowershell

# Install Web Deploy 3.0
RUN choco install -y msdeploy3

# Install WAWSDeploy
RUN choco install -y wawsdeploy

# Install Python
#RUN choco install -y python3 --params "/InstallDir:C:\Python"
#ENV PYTHONPATH=C:\Python\python.exe
```

Comment: share your full Dockerfile please

Comment: This seems to be related: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/902 All in all, docker for windows is still in an early phase.

Comment: `RUN choco install -y python3 --params /InstallDir:""C:\Python""`

Comment: @Alex - Posted my Dockerfile.

Comment: @XtremeBiker - Yea I was looking at that issue as well.  There's a bunch of similar issues (some about too many commands, some about volumes, some about disk space limitations).  It seems this error is just kinda a generic *bad things happened* error.  Which is fine, I just wanna know how to clear it out and get back to where it worked before!

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/packages/python3/3.6.3 .  `RUN choco install -y python3 --params '"/InstallDir:C:\Python"'`

Comment: @Alex - Same error.  And this time I get it during build.

Comment: but can you just execute this command on your machine? are you sure that choco command is valid? try to build image and container without last commands - connect to terminal and run this command - does it work???

Comment: @Alex The choco command is valid and works on the host.  The Dockerfile no longer builds with or without the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I seemed to have solved it.  At least in my case since, as mentioned in the comments, this error is rather generic and doesn't mean one thing in particular.

First, I had to completely comment out everything from my Dockerfile after installing Chocolately on down.  This built and also ran.  Next, I uncommented one thing at a time.  Each time, I'd build and run.  Eventually, I'd run into the error (either building or running) and I'd shift some things around and maybe it would work another time.  No matter what I tried, I could never get everything to run.

The overall issue, it seems, is that you just can't do that many things in a single Docker build.  I believe I was hitting some sort of limit with the number of layers that could be built.

**The Solution:**

It turns out Chocolately is able to install multiple packages at once.  So, I replaced all my `RUN` commands with a single one:

```
# Install packages for build
RUN choco install -y nodejs gulp-cli wawsdeploy msdeploy3 azurepowershell sqlserver-cmdlineutils
```

This resulted in a much faster build and also got rid of the errors.  I could probably do the same by running multiple commands with a single `RUN` statement as well.  Suffice to say, it appears this error had to do with building too many layers and running out of resources in some way.  Not sure why I didn't have this issue building on Windows Server 2016; perhaps the machine specs were different or there's some other factors at play.